# Get category id's from post id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

A post is linked with many categories.Is there any way to list all category id which the post is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get_the_terms to achieve this, you need to pass the post id and taxonomy and terms will be returned in an array.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/